# Choose between two items based upon a given percentage

Tags: php, arrays, random, percentage

I need to display one of two items in an array based up on a 40/60% ratio. So, 40% of the time, item one displays and 60% of the time, item two displays.

I now have the following code that will just randomly choose between the two, but need a way to add the percentage weight to it.

```
$items = array("item1","item2");
$result = array_rand($items, 1);

echo $items[$result];
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you keep the current ratio of both in a dabate? I think it is the only way to ensure that they will be displayed exactly with the ratio you want. But in this case you need to change the code.

Comment: no, it doesn't have to be that exact, just based on probability. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like that should do the trick

```
$result = $items[ rand(1, 100) > 40 ? 1 : 0 ];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$val = rand(1,100);
if($val <= 40)
  return $items[0]; 
else 
  return $items[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use normal `rand` method:

```
if (rand(1,10) <= 4) {
    $result = $items[0];
} else {
    $result = $items[1];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if(rand(0, 100) <= 40) {
    # Item one
} else {
    # Item two
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about ?

```
$rand = mt_rand(1, 10);
echo (($rand > 4) ? 'item2' : 'item1');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$index = rand(1,10) <= 4 ? 0 : 1;
echo $items[$index];
```